# A Mentor's Reassurance - The disturbed books

Tags: visual, rebus, knowledge

I came home, today, and several of my books had pages torn out, and the words turned to images.  I've been able to replace a few of them and, strangely, the pages became intact, with their words, when I did so, but I can't figure out where this page goes:

[image: You]
[image: Are]
[image: Not]
[image: Going]
[image: To]
[image: Find]
[image: The]
[image: Answer]
[image: Here]
[image: So]
[image: Try]
[image: Using]
[image: Another]
[image: Method]

Can anyone help??

Note: Keep in mind that some of the images may only refer to a part of what they are, rather than the whole.

Comment: So we're looking for a book of some sort?

Comment: You're seeking a quote that should indicate what book the page came from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've got the quote:

> "Of course it is all happening inside your head, Harry, but why on earth should that mean that it is not real?" -Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, J.K. Rowling

Explanation

> Corset -> 'Course it
>  Elsa -> "is all" and the beginning of "happening"
>  Pinion -> middle of "happening" and "in"
>  Side -> from the vehicle called a "Side by Side"
>  Red -> end of "your" + "head"
>  Dairy -> end of "head" + "Harry"
>  Bud -> but
>  Whiners -> "why on earth" + beginning of "should"
>  Old Hat -> end of "should" + that
>  Mena (Suvari) -> "mean" + beginning of "that"
>  tit(mouse) -> end of "that" + it
>  snot -> is not
>  tree -> end of "not" and beginning of "real"
>  ale -> end of "real"

As for the puzzle's title:

> This is Harry being reassured by his mentor, Dumbledore

Comment: I had opinion stuck in my head.  Good work!

Comment: It's "old hat"...

Comment: @LeppyR64 Thanks. I don't know why I didn't get "old"!

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Ah, I'd never heard that term before. Only knew them as dune buggies.

Comment: Yeah, my alternative was showing a side-view of a person or building, etc.  I got lucky and ran into side-by-side, but felt I needed to add the "Note" at the bottom of the puzzle because of it.  I hadn't heard of them, either, til I found [this](http://www.arcticcat.com/dirt/side-by-sides/).

Comment: I have to say it like Hagrid to make sense but the quote is Dumbledore.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Yeah, I found that a bit ironic.